# Generate XML Files Used by JUnit Reports

Tags: xml, testing, selenium, junit, testng

I want to create test reports generated by JUnit / TestNG PROGRAMMATICALLY. So, that rules out ANT. My main concern is to generate XML files which are created by Junit while executing test cases. I'have read that RunListener could help me achieve that, but i havn't been able to figure out how ? I'm using Selenium to created my test cases.

How can i generate XML files which are created by JUnit ?

Comment: use the JUnit XML [format](http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/JUnit+Format)

Answer (score 9):

JUnit does not generate XML reports. There isn't a standard XML output format for JUnit.

Other tools generate XML, such as Ant/Maven. So the first thing you need to do is to decide which form of XML file you want, as in what you want to do with the files once you've created them.

And, actually, your restriction of programmatically doesn't rule out ANT. You can invoke ant programmatically (see [Invoke ant from java, then return to java after ant termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714262/invoke-ant-from-java-then-return-to-java-after-ant-termination)). This would probably be the easiest way to generate files which are ant-compatible.

If you wish to create your own XML files, then you can create a class which extends [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html), and then run your tests by invoking [JUnitCore#run()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#run%28java.lang.Class...%29), or similar.

```
public void main(String... args) {
    JUnitCore core= new JUnitCore();
    core.addListener(new RingingListener());
    core.run(MyTestClass.class);
}
```

Your RunListener would just emit the appropriate XML. It is fairly easy to understand: override the methods testRunStarted() etc and write out the XML. For an example of how it works, see [TextListener](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/TextListener.java), which does the same thing, but for text.

Comment: TextListener paga has been removed. Can u share some another link?

Answer (score 4):

xml files are generated by ant-junit, and we can do that by program, the code will look like next :

```
Project project = new Project();
JUnitTask task = new JUnitTask();
project.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir",String); //set temporary directory
task.setProject(project);
JUnitTask.SummaryAttribute sa = new JUnitTask.SummaryAttribute();
sa.setValue("withOutAndErr");
task.setFork(false);
task.setPrintsummary(sa);
FormatterElement formater = new FormatterElement();         
FormatterElement.TypeAttribute type = new FormatterElement.TypeAttribute();
type.setValue("xml");
formater.setType(type);
task.addFormatter(formater);
JUnitTest test = new JUnitTest(String);// set Test.class.getname()          
test.setTodir(File); // set Location for your report
task.addTest(test);         
task.execute();
```

Comment: Which jar files did tou use? Can u please share?

Comment: "org.apache.ant:ant:1.10.10" and "ant:ant-junit:1.6.5"

Answer (score 2):

As being mentioned JUnit does not generate reports. But if you use Maven executing
`mvn clean install test surefire-report:report`
will do the trick

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-report-generation-example/

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it.

```java
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
    .selectors(
        selectPackage("com.example.mytests"),
        selectClass(MyTestClass.class)
    )
    .filters(
        includeClassNamePatterns(".*Tests")
    )
    .build();

LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener listener = new LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener(
                Path.of("."), new PrintWriter(System.out));

try (LauncherSession session = LauncherFactory.openSession()) {
    Launcher launcher = session.getLauncher();
    // Register a listener of your choice
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    // Discover tests and build a test plan
    TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
    // Execute test plan
    launcher.execute(testPlan);
    // Alternatively, execute the request directly
    launcher.execute(request);
}
```

Add this to your pom.xml:

```xml
        <!-- For LauncherSession -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When run, this created a file `TEST-junit-jupiter.xml` in the standard JUnit format.

References:

- [Executing Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-execution)
- [LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener javadoc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.0/api/org.junit.platform.reporting/org/junit/platform/reporting/legacy/xml/LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

You asked nearly the same 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060154/create-test-reports-programmatically-not-using-ant-in-selenium-using-junit-t/9060891#9060891)
If you look at the TestNG doc you can use :

> The org.testng.IReporter interface which only has one method:
>   public void generateReport(List suites, String outputDirectory)
>   This method will be invoked by TestNG when all the suites have been run and you can inspect its parameters to access all the information on the run that was just completed.